# Creating preUpdate or preFlush event with Event Listener

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a onFlush() event which works fine but what I need to do is to turn that into preFlush() or preUpdate() both acceptable. I did preFlush() but for some reason it doesn't do anything. Not even an error. What am I missing?

**TEST:** I placed `exit` in `preFlush()` to see if it is being called at all or not. Outcome is: **1** so `foreach()` is never run! It is an empty array. I also tested preUpdate() and all the lines in that get runed but no data inserted.

```
public function preFlush(PreFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
    echo '1';
    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        echo '2';
        if ($entity instanceof User) {
            echo '3';
        }
    }
    exit;
}
```

I created them after reading the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html).

**service.yml**

```
services:
    entity.event_listener.user:
        class:  Site\FrontBundle\EventListener\Entity\UserListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onFlush }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preFlush }
```

**Working onFlush() example:**

```
class UserListener
{
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
            if ($entity instanceof User) {
                $userLog = new UserLog();
                $userLog->setDescription($entity->getId() . ' being updated.');

                $em->persist($userLog);

                // Instead of $em->flush() cos we're already in flush process
                $userLogMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($userLog));
                $uow->computeChangeSet($userLogMetadata, $userLog);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Not working preFlush() example:**

```
class UserListener
{
    public function preFlush(PreFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
            if ($entity instanceof User) {
                $userLog = new UserLog();
                $userLog->setDescription($entity->getId() . ' being updated.');

                $em->persist($userLog);

                // Instead of $em->flush() cos we're already in flush process
                $userLogMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($userLog));
                $uow->computeChangeSet($userLogMetadata, $userLog);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Not working preUpdate() example**

```
class UserListener
{
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        if ($entity instanceof User) {
            $userLog = new UserLog();
            $userLog->setDescription($entity->getId() . ') been updated.');

            $em = $args->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($userLog);
            $userLogMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($userLog));
            $uow->computeChangeSet($userLogMetadata, $userLog);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the service configuration part?

Comment: @devsheeep - Updated the post for it.

Comment: Could you show code where you call persist and flush methods?

Comment: In a controller as a basic example. E.g. `$user = new User; $user->setName('abc'); $em->flush();` There is no persist cos this is an update action of symfony2.

Comment: Inside preFlush you should use $args->getEntity() instead of $uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates().

Comment: @aljana - `PreFlushEventArgs` does not provide `getEntity()` method for us to use.

Comment: You're right, sorry. Well I'd suggest you to write your own events for creating logs because doctrine's events are tricky when it comes to inserting new entities.

Comment: @aljana - No problem at all. I've found one example. I'll modify it and post it here for others to see how it should be handled.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

The trick is, persisting after `preUpdate()` within `postFlush()` event.

***Note:*** Although this might not be the best solution, it answers the question however it could be done with an Event Subscriber or simple `onFlush()` -> `$uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates()` in an Event Listener.

**Service.yml**

```
services:

    entity.event_listener.user_update:
        class:  Site\FrontBundle\EventListener\Entity\UserUpdateListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postFlush }
```

**Event Listener**

```
<?php

namespace Site\FrontBundle\EventListener\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;
use Site\FrontBundle\Entity\User;
use Site\FrontBundle\Entity\UserLog;

class UserUpdateListener
{
    private $log = array();

    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        // False check is compulsory otherwise duplication occurs
        if (($entity instanceof User) === false) {
            $userLog = new UserLog();
            $userLog->setDescription($entity->getId() . ' being updated.');

            $this->log[] = $userLog;
        }
    }

    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        if (! empty($this->log)) {
            $em = $args->getEntityManager();
            foreach ($this->log as $log) {
                $em->persist($log);
            }
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. It is **NOT SAFE** to call `EntityManager#flush()` inside the `postFlush` event. cf. [Doctrine Documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/events.html#postflush)

Answer (score 2):

Reading the docs,

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush

it doesn't mention that `preFlush` has the infor about changes(I mean the entityManager)

if you look at `Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork` you see that change sets are computed after `preFlush` event so you should use `onFlush` if you want to interact with changed entities

```
// Raise preFlush
    if ($this->evm->hasListeners(Events::preFlush)) {
        $this->evm->dispatchEvent(Events::preFlush, new PreFlushEventArgs($this->em));
    }

// Compute changes done since last commit.
if ($entity === null) {
    $this->computeChangeSets();
} elseif (is_object($entity)) {
    $this->computeSingleEntityChangeSet($entity);
} elseif (is_array($entity)) {
    foreach ($entity as $object) {
        $this->computeSingleEntityChangeSet($object);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to abort the flush operation if some condition fails in `onFlush()` listener functions?

Answer (score 1):

Dear **BentCoder**:
I'm using Symfony 2.7 version. When using *$em->flush* in event listener like your post, this error was occur:
[click-here-to-see-bug-description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsmkL.png)

And, this is my solution:
**Service.yml**

```
services:
    app.listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\DoctrineListener
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate, method: preUpdate }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postUpdate, method: postUpdate }
```

**Event Listener**

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

use AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Log activity on website
 * Class DoctrineListener
 * @package AppBundle\EventListener
 */
class DoctrineListener
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $_container;

    /**
     * @var Array
     */
    private $_activities;

    /**
     * DoctrineListener constructor.
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->_container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $activityEntity = new Entity\Activity();
        $activityEntity->setAction(Entity\Activity::ACTION_EDIT);
        $activityEntity->setActionAt(new \DateTime());
        $activityEntity->setIpAddress($this->_container->get('request')->getClientIp());
        switch (true) {
            case $entity instanceof Entity\Goods:
                $repository = $entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Goods');
                $activityEntity->setType(Entity\Activity::TYPE_GOODS);
                $message = 'User: <strong>%s</strong> sửa mẫu hàng hóa <strong>%s</strong>';
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
        if (isset($repository) && $args->getEntityChangeSet()) {
            $user = $this->_container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
            $recordBefore = clone $entity;
            foreach ($args->getEntityChangeSet() as $key => $value) {
                $method = 'set'.ucfirst($key);
                $recordBefore->$method($value[0]);
            }
            $activityEntity->setFosUser($user);
            $activityEntity->setRecordBefore(serialize($recordBefore));
            $activityEntity->setRecordAfter(serialize($entity));
            $activityEntity->setMessage(
                sprintf(
                    $message,
                    $user->getUserProfile()->getFullName(),
                    (string) $recordBefore
                )
            );
            $this->_activities[] = $activityEntity;
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        if (sizeof($this->_activities)) {
            $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
            foreach ($this->_activities as $activity) {
                $entityManager->persist($activity);
            }
            $entityManager->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help someone!