# symfony: event listener for entity not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, event-listener

I have this event listener below, but it is not working:

```
<?php
namespace Project\BackendBundle\EventListener;
//src/Project/BackendBundle/EventListener/ClippedImagesManager.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;
use Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Subitem;
class ClippedImagesManager
{
public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
die("Event listener!!!");
}



//src/Project/BackendBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    project.clipped_images_manager:
        class: Project\BackendBundle\EventListener\ClippedImagesManager
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

I expected "Event listener!!" was fired when updating any entity inside `BackendBundle`.

Comment: Is your services file being loaded?  You can use app/console container:debug to verify your service definition is being found.  Of course you do have 8k rep so you probably have already checked this.

Comment: And you do understand that events are only fired on flush()?  Not as soon as the entity is changed?

Answer (score 1):

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439422/creating-preupdate-or-preflush-event-with-event-listener/26495114#26495114) before.
Stripped off example below is same as yours but to see the full working example visit the post please. The trick is, persisting after `preUpdate()` within `postFlush()` event.

**Note:** Although this might not be the best solution, it could be done with an Event Subscriber or simple `onFlush() -> $uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates()` in an Event Listener.

**Service.yml**

```
services:

    entity.event_listener.user_update:
        class:  Site\FrontBundle\EventListener\Entity\UserUpdateListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

**Event Listener**

```
<?php

namespace Site\FrontBundle\EventListener\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Site\FrontBundle\Entity\User;

class UserUpdateListener
{
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        // False check is compulsory otherwise duplication occurs
        if (($entity instanceof User) === false) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```